# NSArray how do I restrict data in array when app not purchased?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

I have an app that has a total of 32 images that appear at random;

I would like it to be so that, if the user has not purchased a particular upgrade then only the first 16 (f1.png - f16.png only) from the array will show, however if they have bought the purchase, then all 32 would be available at random.

The in-app id's that would allow ALL of the images are;

com.myphotofun.upgrade16more
&
com.myphotofun.complete

The code to call the random array is;

```
-(void)randImage
{
    NSArray *myImageNames = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"f1.png", @"f2.png", @"f3.png",@"f4.png",@"f5.png",@"f6.png",@"f7.png",@"f8.png",@"f9.png",@"f10.png",@"f11.png",@"f12.png",@"f13.png",@"f14.png",@"f15.png",@"f16.png","f17.png","f18.png","f19.png","f20.png","f21.png","f22.png","f23.png","f24.png","f25.png","f26.png","f27.png","f28.png","f29.png","f30.png","f31.png","f32.png",nil];

           int index = arc4random() % [myImageNames count];

    UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:[myImageNames objectAtIndex:index]];

    [PaintingImage setImage:myImage];
}
```

Now changed to (with thanks to guenis) ;

```
-(void)randImage
{

NSInteger index = arc4random_uniform([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:PRODUCT_PURCHASED] ? 32 : 16);

UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"f%d.png",index +1]];

    [PaintingImage setImage:myImage];

}
```

Any code assistance would be much appreciated.
Thanks,

Chris

Comment: Maybe only put 16 items in the array until the app is paid for?  Maybe use an `if` statement to limit the array index to 15?  But you have code above, what more do you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-(void)randImage
{
    NSArray *myImageNames = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"f1.png", @"f2.png", @"f3.png",@"f4.png",@"f5.png",@"f6.png",@"f7.png",@"f8.png",@"f9.png",@"f10.png",@"f11.png",@"f12.png",@"f13.png",@"f14.png",@"f15.png",@"f16.png","f17.png","f18.png","f19.png","f20.png","f21.png","f22.png","f23.png","f24.png","f25.png","f26.png","f27.png","f28.png","f29.png","f30.png","f31.png","f32.png",nil];

    NSInteger index = arc4random_uniform([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:PRODUCT_PURCHASED] ? 32 : 16);

    UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:[myImageNames objectAtIndex:index]];

    [PaintingImage setImage:myImage];
}
```

Don't forget to set the value when product is purchased

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:PRODUCT_PURCHASED];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Also if your images are named exactly like you have shown I would prefer accessing them with dynamic strings instead of storing them in an nsarray:

```
    NSInteger index = arc4random_uniform([[NSUserDefaults standartUserDefaults] boolForKey:PRODUCT_PURCHASED] ? 32 : 16);

    UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"f%d.png",index + 1]];
```

Comment: Hi Guenis, I have updated my original question with your improved code, one question also, whereabouts do I put those NSUSerDefaults ? And how does it know about the in app ids I mentioned?
Thanks, Chris

Comment: nsuserdefaults is for storing user settings, you set values in it specified by keys and then retrieve them using the same key. the keys have nothing to do with in app product identifiers you may set any string. but it is convenient to use product id in the key, so instead of PRODUCT_PURCHASED you may set the in app product id (with a suffix, prefix or none) and when user purchases it successfully you update the value in nsuserdefaults for that product to true.

Comment: I see, so could I use this;
`-(void)randImage
{

NSInteger index = arc4random_uniform([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"com.myphotofun.upgrade16more"] ? 32 : 16);

UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"f%d.png",index +1]];

    [PaintingImage setImage:myImage];
    
}`

Would that be an acceptable way ?

Comment: yes you can just don't forget to `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"com.myphotofun.upgrade16more"]; [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];` when product purchased message comes from the apple servers.

Comment: For some reason it does not show those extra 16 images after the upgrade? Is there a way to skip the files, so the random is never the same ? (so for the 32 in total, each press just makes it the next image, until the end, then it starts again? Because right now it might be image3, then i press again, and image3 again, or image4 then image3 again etc

Comment: before going on for that tell me if [[NSUserDefaults standartUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"com.myphotofun.upgrade16more"] returns true at any time.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29336/discussion-between-user1695971-and-guenis)

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can try with this

```
    - (void)randImage {

    int items = isPurchased ? 32 : 15;

    NSMutableArray *images = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (int i = 1; i <= items; i++) {
        [images addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"f%i.png", i]];
    }

    int index = arc4random() % [images count];

    UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:[images objectAtIndex:index]];
    [PaintingImage setImage:myImage];

    //Check if it works
    NSLog(@"%@", [images objectAtIndex:index]);
    NSLog(@"%i", images.count);
}
```

already tested

Good Luck